# Dynamically add jQuery UI tabs that load content via ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, tabs

How do I dynamically add a new tab to an existing jQuery UI tab widget that loads content via ajax? I can get content to load via ajax just fine for static tabs, but when I try to add a tab dynamically, when clicking it it'll load the page normally, like a plain link and not use ajax to do it. Here's the code I'm using

```
$('<li><a href="Aditivos.aspx?c_id=1&id=2&type=type">The Text</a></li>').appendTo("#tabs-inner-ad .ui-tabs-nav");
$("#tabs-inner-ad").tabs("refresh");
```

Is there an official way to do this or is it just not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My original code had the **appendTo** part inside a callback and the **refresh** was happening outside of it. Simply putting the **refresh** in the callback solved it.